# ArcGIS Pro: Definition Query > Create new definition query in SQL

Tags: arcgis-pro, sql, features, query, select

I have one point type feature class and another feature class with a polygon.
Using ArcGIS Pro, in the feature class type point > Definition Query > create new definition query in SQL.
I want as a result the points that are inside that polygon.
Only SQL code will be used.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please tale the [Tour]. Your Question is not particularly clear. You can only have a spatial constraint in an RDBMS which supports spatial operators (not shapefile or file geodatabase), but if the geographic boundary is encoded in a attribute, the SQL would be very basic.

Comment: What kind of geodatabase? Oracle 18c? File geodatabase?

Answer (score 0):

Definition queries work with attributes so your points need to be attributed with the polygon ID. You achieve that by using the [Spatial Join tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-spatial-join.htm) then you can apply the definition query.

But if what you want is a "quick a dirt technique" for hiding all points outside your polygon then *visually* you can use the clipping properties of the Map.

Before:

[image: Catchment]

Setting up visual clipping:

[image: clip]

Results:

[image: Results of clip]

Be aware such data is just being visually clipped so if you do any geoprocessing then all points would be included.

Answer (score 0):

With Field Calculator you can set a specific attribute using Select by Location between the polygon and the point.

Then set your DQuery using this new attribute.

If you don't want to make set a new attribute, you can right click on the layer with the selected points > selection > create new layer w/ selected features.

Visual Clipping is also a good option.